# Angular2 Rxjs keyup how to concat characters

Tags: angular, rxjs5

My goal is to concat the characters
typed in a input like this

```
<input #term (keyup)="search()">
```

so I tried with

```
const obs$: Observable<KeyboardEvent> = Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.term), 'keyup');
    obs$
    .debounceTime(500)
    .map(ev => ev.key)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .scan((acc, one) => acc + one)
    .do(x => console.log(x))
    .subscribe(term => this.search(term));
```

and it's all good until you don't use backspace
just an example to catch the point

```
a
app.component.ts:49 av
app.component.ts:49 avf
app.component.ts:49 avfd
app.component.ts:49 avfdBackspace
app.component.ts:49 avfdBackspaced
app.component.ts:49 avfdBackspaceds
app.component.ts:49 avfdBackspacedsw
app.component.ts:49 avfdBackspacedswControl
```

so what I can use without to get the right input ?

UPDATE

I could do like

```
term$ = new Subject<string>();
(input)=term$.next($event.target.value)
```

but I'd like to do it with fromEvent

UPDATE2 (see the reply of @meligy)

```
Observable.fromEvent<HTMLInputElement>(this.getNativeElement(this.term), 'keyup')
    .debounceTime(500)
    .map(ev => ev.target.value)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .do(termDebug => console.log(termDebug))
    .switchMap(term => this.service.search(term))
    .subscribe(result => this.items = result);
```

Comment: Why dont you create a form and listen to modelChanges or (ngModelChange) and two way bind it ? You can still use the same logic, but the source wont be this ```Observable.fromEvent(this.getNativeElement(this.term), 'keyup');```, but from some other source.. easiest would be a subject on which you will call next() in (ngModelChanges) handler

Comment: That is obv because evt.key is a string from which key is pressed, and not the context (letters and numbers).. arrowUp, down, shift etc are not a real context right

Comment: @DenkoMancheski easiest would be a subject on which you will call next() yeah I did that in my Update but since I'm learning rxjs I'm curious to see if there is a way to accomplish my goal with my example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have access to `target` when using `fromEvent()`. You can just type `ev.target.value`.

Comment: it works like a charme :) (look at UPDATE2) but I've got an other problem Property 'target' does not exist on type 'HTMLInputElement'. I also tried with HTMLElement and EventTarget with no luck can you help me again ? please :)

Comment: `ev` would be of type `KeyboardEvent` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent

Comment: It was my first try but I've got Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'